# Parse DateTime with and without leading zeros

Tags: c#, date, datetime, tryparse

I have a TextBox in which the user can type a date. I only expect following formats:

```
12.12.2017
12.02.2017
12.2.2017
02.12.2017
2.12.2017
02.02.2017
2.2.2017
```

So there can be a leading zero or not.

I am currently parsing the DateTime with following code:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime();
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(TboDate.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                   CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate);
```

Dates like `12.2.2017` can not be parsed successfully with that code. But I don't want to check the string everytime and parse it then with the matching format `d.M.yyyy, dd.M.yyyy, d.MM.yyyy` and so on. Is there an easier way to tell the method, that there can be leading zeros?

Comment: I suspect that `d.M.yyyy` will handle leading zeroes. If not, use the overload of `TryParseExact` that supports multiple formats.

Comment: I have checked it, they could all be parsed without a problem with `Parse`/`TryParse`: `DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)`

Comment: Your both solutions work. Thanks I've never thought about TryParse.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They could all be parsed without a problem with `Parse`/`TryParse` f.e. with de-DE culture:

```
var dates = new[] { "12.12.2017", "12.02.2017", "12.2.2017", "02.12.2017", "2.12.2017", "02.02.2017", "2.2.2017" };      

foreach (var dateStr in dates)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not valid: " + dateStr);
    }
}
```

But you could also use `ParseExact` if you specify all allowed formats:

```
string[] allowedFormats = { "dd.MM.yyyy", "d.MM.yyyy", "dd.M.yyyy", "d.M.yyyy" };
foreach (var dateStr in dates)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, allowedFormats, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not valid: " + dateStr);
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

As Jon Skeet has mentioned it's not necessary to specify multiple, this handles all: `"d.M.yyyy"`